# Jquery Auto complete focus is lost

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

All

I'm using JQuery autocomplete. It's really awesome.
I need  help from your side  to use this component  for my requirement in a better way.

Problem:

1.Using up and down arrow keys one can navigate within the auto complete list box. While doing so once I reach the end I mean when the focus is on the last item in the list,Still if I press down arrow key,Focus is not coming to the first element immediately and there is some delay(one key up delay). How can I  fix this issue ?

Plz see the demo given in the following site

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Type  character 'a' in the text box shown.

Once the last item in the list (**Scala**) focussed. Now if I press down arrow key the first item i.e **ActionScript** is not getting highlighted (I mean not focussed)  immediately.

So, My queries are

1.Is there any way of focusing first item immediately(after last item) without any delay.?

2.Is it possible to restrict the focus event (so that I can focus last item always once I reached the end).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to auto select options, look at this site: http://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions

i was using this code (for JSon Result):

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
CityAC: function (selectorOrCountry) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var el = $(this);
        var id = el.attr("id");
        var md = el.metadata();
        var parentEl = $('#' + md.parentId);

        el.autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var selectedCountry = "";
                if (selectorOrCountry !== undefined && selectorOrCountry !== null) {
                    if ($(selectorOrCountry).size() > 0) {
                        selectedCountry = $(selectorOrCountry).val();
                    } else {
                        selectedCountry = selectorOrCountry;
                    }
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Jx/GetCities',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { text: request.term, country: selectedCountry },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data != null) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.Name,
                                    value: item.Code
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                el.val(ui.item.label);
                parentEl.val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            },
            minLength: 2
        }).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            var templateItem = $('<a></a>');

            templateItem.append('<img src="/Assets/images/icon_town.png" width="16" align="absmiddle" class="ui-menuitem-icon" />');
            templateItem.append(item.label);

            return $('<li></li>')
            .data('item.autocomplete', item)
            .append(templateItem)
            .appendTo(ul);
        };

        if (md.label !== undefined && md.label !== null) {
            el.val(md.label);
            parentEl.val(md.value);
            parentEl.data(md.country);
        }
    });
}
});


$('#inputID').CityAC();
```

Comment: Hi, Thank u for your reply. The code you are suggested is very useful for auto select and for auto focus. But My actual intension is asking this question is ,The focus should come to first item in the list immediately after the last item in the list. But right now it's not actually coming immediately there is a delay of one key up in moving from last item to the first item. Can you please suggest  in that way. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

This code is to override the standard ui.autocomplete method:

```
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._move = function(direction, event) {

        if ( !this.menu.element.is( ":visible" ) ) {
            this.search( null, event );
            return;
        }
        if ( this.menu.isFirstItem() && /^previous/.test( direction ))
        {
            this._value( this.term );
            this.menu._move( "first", "first", event );
        }
        else if ( this.menu.isLastItem() && /^next/.test( direction ))
        {
            this._value( this.term );
            this.menu._move( "last", "last", event );
        }

        this.menu[ direction ]( event );
    };
```